# ¿ Como tener un texto por defecto en los precios de WooCoommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, users-roles

Quiero añadir un texto a los precios de mis productos en WooCommerce.
Lo conseguí con una función que muestro :

```
function custom_price_message( $price ) { 
    global $post;
    $product_id = $post->ID;
    $textafter = ' (P.V.P.)'; //texto que vamos agregar
    return $price . '' . $textafter . ''; //class textafter para el CSS
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );
```

Ahora, tengo un complemento para mostrar diferentes precios según el rool del usuario registrado.
Las funciones funcionan, ya que si me registro con el rool de Customer, se muestra el texto necesario ( P.V.P.) detrás del precio
Y si me registro con el rool de "Wholesale Customer", tambien se muestra el precio correcto y el texto correcto (P.V.M.)

El problema es que cuando llegamos a la web por primera vez, antes de registrarnos, no muestra ningún texto detrás del precio, y debería mostrar el precio y texto como cuando nos registramos como rool Customer (P.V.P)

No se como crear el condicional, he probado a añadir el texto cuando pongo el `array()` en la primera función, pero se rompe la web .

¿ Que debo hacer para que los precios tengan por defecto el texto de Customer (P.V.P.)?

Esto es lo que he conseguido hasta ahora:

```
function my_get_current_user_roles() {
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
    return $roles; // This will returns an array
  } else {
    return  array();
  }
}

function custom_price_message( $price ) { 
 global $post; 
 $product_id = $post->ID; 
 $roles = my_get_current_user_roles();
 $textafter = "";
 if(!empty($roles)) { 
    if (in_array("Wholesale Customer", $roles)) {
        $textafter = 'P.V.M.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
    }
    if (in_array("customer", $roles)) {
        $textafter = 'P.V.P.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
    }
 } 
 return $price . '' . $textafter . ''; //class textafter para el  
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basándome en:

> El problema es que cuando llegamos a la web por primera vez, antes de registrarnos

Asumí que podría perfectamente modificar tu código para mostrarlo en uno de mis sitios, y créeme solo me hizo falta analizar el if y ponerle un else para que me apareciera en la web. Así que te paso el código que funciona perfectamente.

```
    function my_get_current_user_roles() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
        return $roles; // This will returns an array
    } else {
        return  array();
    }
}

function custom_price_message( $price ) { 
    global $post; 
    $product_id = $post->ID; 
    $roles = my_get_current_user_roles();
    $textafter = "";
    if(!empty($roles)) { 
        if (in_array("Wholesale Customer", $roles)) {
            $textafter = 'P.V.M.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
        }
        if (in_array("customer", $roles)) {
            $textafter = 'P.V.P.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
        }
    }
    else{
        $textafter = ' (P.V.P.)'; // Or whatever you want
    }
    return $price . '' . $textafter . ''; //class textafter para el  
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message');
```

Comment: Funciona bien, tiene un pequeño inconveniente, y es que registrado como `Wholesale Customer`,  si en un producto no tengo asignado un precio en el `rool` de `Wholesale Custome`, no muestra ningún texto detrás del precio. Por eso digo en la pregunta que, por defecto, mostrara siempre P.V.P. Acepto la respuesta por valida. Si se te ocurre como puedo solucionar este inconveniente,  te escucharía con gusto. Gracias por tu rapida respuesta @OCHOA

Comment: Pero porque quiere que aparezca el texto sino hay un precio definido??? Además existen productos sin precio en determinados roles? Estoy por salir ahora, mañana hago pruebas poniendo en blanco el precio de algún producto (cosa que nunca he hecho).

Comment: Gracia. No me explique bien. Todos los productos tienen dos precios, uno para `customer` y otro diferente para `Wholesale Customer`, los cuales se añaden desde la pagina del producto al editar. Pero sin el campo de precio de `Wholesale Customer` queda vacío, se muestra el precio por defecto, pero sin ningún texto. El texto por defecto es P.V.P.  Pero puedes estar tranquilo como dije, tu  `else` funciona correctamente. Acepte tu respuesta, solo si tienes idea de lo que digo y se ocurre algo, esta bien, pero no tienes porque...

Comment: Debemos que tener en cuenta, que existen otros tipos  de rool en WordPress. En este caso, es el administrador el que decide el rool de las nuevos usuarios, pero eso es lo que te queria decir.

Comment: Ya entendí, lastimosamente no puedo recrearlo porque no uso roles en mis sitios :-( pero seria muy interesante solventarlo...

Comment: Gracias por tu paciencia @OCHOA, no te preocupes, como te dige, ya me funciona de este modo. Estoy muy agradecido, estaba estancado hasta que llegaste. Ahora me encuentro con otro problema, y es que necesito crear un buscador interno que selecciones los productos por sus ingredientes. Tengo alguna idea, pero no se como ponerlo en practica. Hice una pregunta sobre ello